# How to reuse prefix fast when adding new key in IntelliJ Resource Bundle

Tags: intellij-idea

I have resource bundles with keys grouped by many levels of prefixes. Example:

> admin.common.alert.warning.security.passwordInsecure.tooShort
>   admin.common.alert.warning.security.passwordInsecure.noNumbers

I would like to easily add new keys by reusing certain prefixes, without having to select the prefix, open it in edit mode, copy it, close the dialog, open the add dialog and paste the prefix before adding the suffix.

In eclipse, when viewing the keys hierarchically, I can select a prefix where I want to add a new key, press the add button and the prefix is automatically filled in in the add dialog. Example:

[image]

In IDEA this doesn't happen. Is there any setting or plugin may help speed up adding new keys?

*Note: I am using IDEA Community 2017*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Refactor | Copy (<kbd>F5</kbd> default shortcut) action on a certain selected property.